# System fonts for windows, custom fonts for mac -- using Google fonts API

Tags: css, api, fonts

I've seen similar questions asked before but haven't found a definitive answer.

The client wants to use a specific font for headings because it is part of their logo. They're fine with system fonts for body copy. The custom font is rendering really hideously in Windows (no anti-aliasing). I've read a lot about this issue, and I understand that it has to do with the way Windows renders type, and the solution always seems to be "just use a better font" -- one optimized for screen with better hinting, blah blah blah...

But I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to continue to use the custom font for everybody else but serve system fonts to Windows viewers. Is there a CSS equivalent of conditional comments (such as `<!--[if lt IE 7 ]-->`) that I could use to designate different font stacks for Windows?

I understand that the cleanest solution would be to just to use fonts that work well for everybody, but that's not an option for this project.

Edited to add: Font in question is Ruda: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Ruda

Comment: It’s essential what font this is about. It also seems that there is a misunderstanding about logos: logo is a specific rendering of a company or brand name, for use in an image-like manner, and usually implemented as an image on web pages. So do they really want their logo font to be used for headings? That would more of less defeat the idea of a logo.

Comment: I have worked with Google Fonts, and have not experienced the problem you are describing.  HOWEVER, to answer your question - I think you may be stuck using a [jQuery browser detection](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/) method to add a class for Windows browsers, and you can then over-ride styles with that specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to detect the OS and then replace the class of the header elements with a class that uses a system font. Here is a good tutorial for browser detection:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html